# How to disable ftps/ftp in Azure Functions App using ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm deploying an Azure Functions App using an ARM template and want to disable ftp/ftps access.

The setting is easy to find in the portal:

[image]

How do I find the property or app setting for this so I can configure it in the json ARM template?

I've already tried

- Reviewing [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/sites)
- Running PowerShell commands `Get-AzureRmResource` and `Get-AzureRmWebApp` to explore the returned site objects
- Searching for the property in the [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com)
- Guessing the property name and testing deployments--trial and error

I would expect the setting to exist along with similar settings in the siteConfig:

[image]

Comment: Note on the json screenshot: the `"ftpAccess": "off"` property in the site config was one of my failed trial and error attempts, but the other three properties in that box work as expected.

Comment: The reason I couldn't originally find the property in the Azure Resource Explorer might be because I had never changed it from it's default.  I had assumed the property would exist whether or not it was set to its default value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property you are looking for is `ftpsState`. Here are the possible values:

- `AllAllowed` (that's the default)
- `FtpsOnly`
- `Disabled`

Comment: That property seems to be recognized, but instead of the "Disabled" button now being highlighted in the portal, none of the buttons are highlighted.  I'm guessing this is a bug in the way the portal recognizes the new value. @DavidEbbo

Comment: That's odd, I tried and can't repro that. Does refreshing the portal fix that? BTW, you can use https://resources.azure.com/ to see what things look like at the JSON level. Find the app, and then go under config/web under it. There should be no difference between setting it to Disabled via Portal or via ARM.

Comment: Thanks, I can see it at resources.azure.com and it exists as expected.  The portal issue occurs regardless of whether I configure it via the portal or an ARM template deployment. @DavidEbbo

Comment: So you mean even if you do everything from Portal, you set it to Disabled and then Portal shows nothing highlighted after you save?

Comment: If I set the value to `disabled` (lowercase via arm template), the highlight disappears.  Any attempts to re-save it (via portal or arm template) cause no change, and it remains lowercase and not highlighted.

However, if I initially set it to `Disabled` (propercase) it is highlighted.  Or if I change it to a different setting via the portal and then back to Disabled, it updates the case (to propercase) and remains highlighted.

So it appears the method which gets the value is case specific, and the method that sets the value ignores case.

Comment: Yep, I can repro this. Small bug, I'll let the right people know about it. I think we're done here :)